# Extension of the Capstan Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, string, models

The [Capstan Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capstan_equation) relates the holding force and the load force for a string wrapped around a cylinder. However, most people who work with heavy machinery know that if you wrap a rope around a post and then over itself before attaching it to the load, the holding force is further reduced.

The problem I have is that no equation exists for this scenario, and I am having trouble coming up with one.

At the moment I have two models:

(1) $$T_{load} = T_{hold}\cdot e^{\mu_1\phi_1+(\mu_1+\mu_2)\phi_2}$$

which simplifies into

$$T_{load} = T_{hold}\cdot (e^{\mu_1\phi}\cdot e^{\mu_2\phi_2})$$

(2) $$T_{load} = T_{hold}\cdot (e^{\mu_1\phi}+e^{\mu_2\phi_2})$$

Where:

- $\mu_1$ is the coefficient of friction between the rope and the post
- $\mu_2$ is the coefficient of friction between the rope and itself
- $\phi_1$ is the angle between the first point of contact of the rope on the holding force side and the point of overlap
- $\phi_2$ is the angle between the point of overlap and the first point of contact of the rope on the load force side.
- $\phi = \phi_1 + \phi_2$, or the total angle of the rope

The two models are based off the idea that the overlapping rope increases the friction of the rope beneath it to the post, as well as its own friction on the rope beneath it. I know that this is true because I have seen this method of overlapping rope used on military bases to increase the friction and therefore reduce the holding force.

I'm going to refer to $\frac{T_{load}}{T_{hold}}$ as the multiplying factor (with reference to the two forces).

I'm just unsure of what magnitude of an effect it has on the forces. The first model assumes that the coefficients of friction add, hence multiplying the two multiplying factors together. The second model assumes that the two multiplying factors are added together. I don't know which of the two it is, if either at all, hence the two models and the question.

Can someone offer any ideas as to what the model might be?

Comment: How did you come up with your equation? Please show your calculation. What is your difficulty? You have got an equation - why do you think that it is wrong? On this site questions asking for calculations are required to show effort to solve the problem and ask about a conceptual difficulty.

Comment: I added clarification on the model(s) and why I'm not sure they are correct, but I don't know what you mean by "what is your difficulty".